# does multithreaded multicore cpu renders images faster than single threaded multicore cpu?

Tags: multithreading, performance, rendering, cpu

I've always struggled with the way 3d render engines use CPU. most of the resources said the more threads you have the better the performance gets. let's think of 4 core and 8 threaded CPU, if 2 threads both using the same resource(core) and doing the same job which is rendering pixels, and also the CPU is working on a full load of max frequencies then what's the difference between doing all that calculation on single-core and single thread? will there be any drop in speed?

Answer (score 0):

SMT/hyper-threading provides a small improvement, but on most workloads it is in single figure % points. Most of the gain comes from 2 things:

1. Less context switching on heavily concurrent workloads
2. Higher chance that that the data at least one of the threads needs is going to be in the CPU cache. If there is only one thread on the core, the core has to wait for the data to come from RAM. If there are 2 threads, then there is a chance that the data for the 2nd thread might be in the cache so the core can do something productive while the other data is coming from the RAM.

Answer (score 0):

SMT is used to exploit all the EUs (Execution Units) of a core.

If your CPU can do two additions in a clock but your code has the form:

```
add r0, r0, r1  #r0 = r0 + r1
add r0, r0, r2
add r0, r0, r3
...
```

then you cannot do better than one addition per clock, since each instruction requires the output of the previous one.
This is called a *dependency chain* and software has generally a lot of them.

Good compiler write code that can exploit more parallelism, for example by writing the sum above as the sum of two subsums (that can then proceed in parallel).
But writing this kind of code is hard and *extremely* dependent on the specific microarchitecture (read: model of CPU).
This was a very simple example, sharing the core resources between two threads has its own benefits, also if a thread stalls the other one can take over the EUs rather than leaving them unused.

So, if you can spare "some" transistors, why not add a new execution flow? That's SMT.
As you noticed, SMT is not suitable for very well optimized code. If all the EUs can be optimally exploited by a single thread, having another one is useless.

But you cannot tell (or just assume) that software is optimally compiled for your CPU, so it's worth trying using SMT.
By the way, when people say "the more threads, the better" they generally mean "more EUs", for most software this equals to "more threads" (since most software can use all the EUs in a thread) but for a small percentage it equals to "more core".

In general, do a benchmark.
It happened that I had to write a few cracking programs, I always test them by pinning multiple instances on a thread per core and on all threads and see if there's an improvement.
When I use manually crafted assembly and libraries, there is none.